# Finding XML elements using jquery.find gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am using jquery to help extract information from a sharepoint service, but for some reason some elements can't be found while others can.

Here is the XML string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><entry xml:base="https://geosolutionsnetau.sharepoint.com/Residential/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" m:etag="&quot;7&quot;"><id>747741d3-6f71-424b-898a-3138c285edf5</id><category term="SP.Data.CustomersListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'bf1cef04-e377-4f25-824c-0626557af1ab')/Items(5)" /><title /><updated>2017-07-23T01:59:21Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:Company_x0020_Name>Wilson Homes</d:Company_x0020_Name></m:properties></content></entry>
```

And here is the method I'm using to find elements given that the string is set to a variable called data:

```
$(data).find("updated");
```

Which correctly returns one element, but when trying to find the element called "Company_x0020_Name", it finds nothing. The XML seems to be correctly formed so I don't know why it can't find some elements but can find others.

This is in Firefox and the full jquery request being made is this:

```
$.get( url, function( data ) {
    var xmlElement = $(data).find(fieldName);
    var text = xmlElement.text();
});
```

Comment: Missing starting `<title>` tag at HTML.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean? @guest271314

Comment: The XML contains only closing `</title>` tag, but not opening `<title>` tag. The XML is malformed.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why SharePoint is returning malformed XML.